# My Code Getting Element With <a> and <h1> Tags

Tags: android, string, jsoup

I got my jsoup element to string with this code:

```
Document likesd;
    try {

        likesd = Jsoup.connect(site).ignoreContentType(true).get();
        Elements links = likesd.select("h1");
        Element likess=links.select("a").first();

        mcpe=likess.toString();
    } catch (IOException ex) {}
```

And printed to sharedpreferences with this code.

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pp);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                preferencess=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                editorr = preferencess.edit();
                editorr.putString("build4", mcpe);
            be=preferencess.getString("build4", mcpe);
                editorr.commit();
            }
        });
```

site's code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>cikti</title>
        <h1><a>http://i.androyun.xyz/11</a></h1>
<h2>MCPE 0.13.0 Build 1</h2>
```

kk

But output of this code in my sharedpref.xml,

```
  <string name="build4">&lt;a&gt;http://i.androyun.xyz/11&lt;/a&gt;</string>
```

But I dont want <a> text. What should I do? Thanks to all ^^

Comment: and what is the output you want to become when it's not the text of the <a> tag ?

Comment: Try using [likess.data()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#data--).

Comment: When I used likess.data(), I got empty output. (solved)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try `mcpe=likess.text();`

And read it: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html

Comment: You are the best! Thanks ^^ (I tried likess.text(); before, but I got error.)